# How to use Nifi expression language to change a date into a folder path?

Tags: hadoop, expression, etl, apache-nifi

In nifi, I need to transfer a bunch of json files to HDFS. The json files have a field called "creationDate" which has the date in UNIX format. I need to use the date in there to funnel the file to HDFS directories that are named after dates, like "2019-01-19" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-21" etc.

At first I used an "EvaluateJsonPath" processor going to a "PutHDFS" processor. The "Evaluate..." processor had "creationDate" as the property and "${creationDate} as the value. In the PutHDFS processor, for directory I put "/${creationDate}"

But then I realized that the date in the json file has the full timestamp, like "2019-01-19T04:34:28.527722+00:00

Obviously I don't need all that, just the first eight digits. So how can I turn this big string into a neat 8-digit directory name? Will I need to use a regex, and if so, how can this be implemented? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UpdateAttribute and use the date expression language functions to format it.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html

Example (not specific to your format):

```
${creationDate:toDate('MM-dd-yyyy'):format('yyyy/MM/dd')}
```

In UpdateAttribute you would add a new property name creationDate and set the value to an expression like above.

Comment: Thanks for this. So if I understand correctly, I would need to modify the expression so it matches the original time format? Something like: ${creationDate:toDate('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'):format('yyyy-MM-dd')} ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know the exact date format you need, but something like that, your date had dashes instead of slashes

Comment: http://sdfonlinetester.info This looks close yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ